# не работает функция внутри UseEffect при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-database

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf').

```
const [orders, setOrders] = React.useState() 
const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = React.useState(true);
const {googleSignIn, user} = UserAuth();

React.useEffect(() => {

    setIsFetched(true)

    async function checkKey() {

      try {
          const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
      } catch (e){
            console.log('from try catch', e)
      }

        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

        if (docSnap.exists()) {

            setOrders(docSnap.data().order)

            setIsFetched(false)

        } else {

        }
    }

    checkKey()
},[] )
```

Что я пробовал сделать:
[image: Добавлял console.log в каждую строчку , чтобы выявить ошибку , где перестаёт работать код]

[image: Тут можно увидеть , что код перестаёт работать после 3 строчки]

Comment: Почему вы в `catch` используете `console.log`, а не `console.error`, что более логично и правильно?

Comment: Разве это поможет изменить проблему (?

Comment: Я нашёл обусждение вашей проблемы в enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203300/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-indexof-with-firebase-v9-modular, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72090798/firebase-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-indexof, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72373572/reactjs-firebase-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-index, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71694379/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-indexof

Comment: Я думал над этим , но в итоге у меня практически такой-же код и это не помогло (. Спасибо , что пытаетесь решить эту проблему вместе со мной , но почему-то никто так и не смог решить эту проблему , видимо придётся добавлять кнопку и делать переход с помощью кнопки ( так работает ) , но это выглядит не очень круто

Comment: Офигеть , получилось пофиксить, зависимости useEffect'а не были указаны, установил user и все работает-https://ibb.co/pz6cXRp

Answer (score 0):

проблема решена, зависимости useEffect'а не были указаны, установил user и все работает[image: введите сюда описание изображения]